# "So" meaning "in such a way"

Tags: phrase-usage, phrase-request

A sentence:

> These are the books **so written that** it can bewitch the readers.

Does this mean the same as:

> "These are the books **written in such a way that** it can bewitch the readers."?

Is there any variation in **formality?**

Answer (score 1):

> "These are the books so written that 'they' can bewitch the readers."

> "These are the books written in such a way that 'they' can bewitch the readers."

I changed the 'it' to 'they'.

There is no significant difference between the 2 examples.